# Image Not Displaying in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have an Android ListView here called "mConversationView" in this code:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.phoji.common.logger.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class BluetoothChatFragment extends Fragment {
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 3;
private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatFragment";
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
private BluetoothChatService mChatService = null;
private String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter;
private ListView mConversationView;
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        FragmentActivity activity = BluetoothChatFragment.this.getActivity();
        switch (msg.what) {
            case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE /*1*/:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case 0 /*0*/:
                    case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE /*1*/:
                        BluetoothChatFragment.this.setStatus((int) R.string.title_not_connected);
                        return;
                    case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE /*2*/:
                        BluetoothChatFragment.this.setStatus((int) R.string.title_connecting);
                        return;
                    case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT /*3*/:
                        BluetoothChatFragment bluetoothChatFragment = BluetoothChatFragment.this;
                        BluetoothChatFragment bluetoothChatFragment2 = BluetoothChatFragment.this;
                        Object[] objArr = new Object[BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE];
                        objArr[0] = BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConnectedDeviceName;
                        bluetoothChatFragment.setStatus(bluetoothChatFragment2.getString(R.string.title_connected_to, objArr));
                        BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                        return;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
            case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE /*2*/:
                BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConversationArrayAdapter.add(BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + new String((byte[]) msg.obj, 0, msg.arg1));
                return;
            case BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT /*3*/:
                BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + new String((byte[]) msg.obj));
                return;
            case Log.INFO /*4*/:
                BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME);
                if (activity != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Connected to " + BluetoothChatFragment.this.mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            case Log.WARN /*5*/:
                if (activity != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, msg.getData().getString(Constants.TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                return;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
};
private EditText mOutEditText;
private StringBuffer mOutStringBuffer;
private Button mSendButton;
private LinearLayout inputInterface;
Button keyboard, camera, take;
LinearLayout cameraLayout;
GridLayout grid;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
static int index;

private OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener = new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == 0 && event.getAction() == BluetoothChatFragment.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE) {
            BluetoothChatFragment.this.sendMessage(view.getText().toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    this.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (this.mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        activity.finish();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!this.mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_ENABLE"), REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    } else if (this.mChatService == null) {
        setupChat();
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (this.mChatService != null) {
        this.mChatService.stop();
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (this.mChatService != null && this.mChatService.getState() == 0) {
        this.mChatService.start();
    }
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth_chat, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mConversationView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.in);
    this.mOutEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    this.mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    inputInterface = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.inputInterface);
    keyboard = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
    camera = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    take = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.take);
    cameraLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraLayout);
    cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    grid = (GridLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
}

private void setupChat() {
    Log.d(TAG, "setupChat()");
    this.mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.message);
    this.mConversationView.setAdapter(this.mConversationArrayAdapter);
    this.mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this.mWriteListener);

    inputInterface.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("stuff", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    index = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    int i = 2;
    while (i <= index) {
        String s = "" + i;
        String path = getPath(getActivity(), Uri.parse(prefs.getString(s, "string")));

        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
        Bitmap b = null;

        try {
               b = getResizedBitmap(100,100,path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);
        i++;
    }

    keyboard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mOutEditText.hasFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(mOutEditText, 0);
            }
        }
    });
    camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cameraLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mOutEditText.clearFocus();
            if (view != null) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
    take.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            AlertDialog.Builder dalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            dalert.setTitle("Insert a photo");
            dalert.setNegativeButton("Take from camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 10);
                }
            });
            dalert.setPositiveButton("Choose from gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    gallery.setType("image/*");
                    gallery.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    gallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select an image"), 20);
                }
            });
            dalert.show();
            /*
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            dialog.setTitle("Insert a photo");
            Button n = new Button(getContext());
            n.setText("Take from camera");
            n.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 10);
                }
            });
            Button p = new Button(getContext());
            p.setText("Choose from gallery");
            p.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
                    gallery.setType("image*//*");
                    gallery.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Select an image"), 20);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();*/
        }
    });

    this.mOutEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                inputInterface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                inputInterface.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    this.mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            View view = BluetoothChatFragment.this.getView();
            if (view != null) {
                BluetoothChatFragment.this.sendMessage(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out)).getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
    this.mChatService = new BluetoothChatService(getActivity(), this.mHandler);
    this.mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
}
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(int targetW, int targetH,  String imagePath) {

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    //inJustDecodeBounds = true <-- will not load the bitmap into memory
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);
    return(bitmap);
}

private void ensureDiscoverable() {
    if (this.mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != 23) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent("android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE");
        discoverableIntent.putExtra("android.bluetooth.adapter.extra.DISCOVERABLE_DURATION", 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (this.mChatService.getState() != REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (message.length() > 0) {
        this.mChatService.write(message.getBytes());
        this.mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        this.mOutEditText.setText(this.mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

private void setStatus(int resId) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
        }
    }
}

private void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    if (activity != null) {
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
        }
    }
}
private String savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
    extStorageDirectory+="/Pictures";
    String imgName="IMG_"+seconds+".png";
    extStorageDirectory+="/"+imgName;
    if(!new File(extStorageDirectory).exists())
        new File(extStorageDirectory).mkdir();
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory);
    }
    try {

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        insertImageIntoGallery(getActivity().getContentResolver(),imgName,extStorageDirectory,"");
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    Log.e("Test",extStorageDirectory);
    Log.e("Test",extStorageDirectory);

    return extStorageDirectory;
}
public void insertImageIntoGallery(ContentResolver cr,String path,  String title, String description) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, title);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,path);
    // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
    cr.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (requestCode == 10) {
        //camera
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        String path = savebitmap(photo);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
        int i = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
        i++;
        editor.putInt("index", i);
        editor.putString("" + i, path);
        editor.commit();
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(uri);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);

    }
    if (requestCode == 20) {
        //from gallery
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        int i = prefs.getInt("index", 1);
        i++;
        editor.putInt("index", i);
        editor.putString("" + i, uri.toString());
        editor.commit();
        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(getContext());
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = getThumbnail(getActivity().getContentResolver(), getPath(getContext(), uri));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addImageBetweentext(iv.getDrawable());
            }
        });
        grid.addView(iv);
    }

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE /*1*/:
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                connectDevice(data, true);
                return;
            }
            return;
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE /*2*/:
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                connectDevice(data, false);
                return;
            }
            return;
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT /*3*/:
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                setupChat();
                return;
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getActivity().finish();
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }
}

private void connectDevice(Intent data, boolean secure) {
    this.mChatService.connect(this.mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS)), secure);
}

public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.bluetooth_chat, menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.secure_connect_scan /*2131361822*/:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class), REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_SECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.insecure_connect_scan /*2131361823*/:
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), DeviceListActivity.class), REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE_INSECURE);
            return true;
        case R.id.discoverable /*2131361824*/:
            ensureDiscoverable();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

public static Bitmap getThumbnail(ContentResolver cr, String path) throws Exception {

    Cursor ca = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID}, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=?", new String[]{path}, null);
    if (ca != null && ca.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = ca.getInt(ca.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        ca.close();
        return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, id, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    }

    ca.close();
    return null;

}

private void addImageBetweentext(Drawable drawable) {
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

    int selectionCursor = mOutEditText.getSelectionStart();
    //et.setText(et.getText().toString()+" ");

    mOutEditText.getText().insert(selectionCursor, " ");
    selectionCursor = mOutEditText.getSelectionStart();

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(mOutEditText.getText());
    builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(drawable), selectionCursor-1 , selectionCursor,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mOutEditText.setText(builder);
    mOutEditText.setSelection(selectionCursor);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

How do I replace this with a TextView that supports images or get this ListView to support images entered by the EditText mOutEditText?

Comment: Couldnt understand your question. Can you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: I currently have a listview right now that I use to display my messages.  I need to get this so I can use not just text but text with inlined images.  So images in the text.  What I am trying to determine is what widget should I use to accomplish this task(text with inline images)?

Comment: Or how do I add support for inline images in the ListView?

Comment: You can just use Imageview control in your custom_list_item.xml layout alongwith TextView inorder to display both.

Comment: For displaying text above image try encapsulating both in RelativeLayout. :) Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I would want to display the text inlined with the image.  Horizontal not vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Alright! for that you need to use  [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) from API 1 like this :

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append("My string. I ")
        .append(" ", new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_heart), 0)
        .append(" Cree by Dexode");

textView.setText(builder);
```